# Short story: brain chip for anger management

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

### What I remember from the plot:

In this short story, a man who suffers of anger management problems (probably on criminal levels, or in order to prevent them) gets an advanced, experimental treatment based on electrical stimuli directly to the brain.

These stimuli are controlled by a chip implanted in his brain; the position of the electric contacts is extremely important, because missing the exact point of the brain to control would lead to disastrous results.

The chip would detect "anger spikes" and would stimulate the brain in order to reduce them and prevent any anger explosion from the guy.

The problem is that, when the anger spike is prevented, it is kind of replaced by a pleasant sensation. This causes a feedback loop where the brain subcounsciosly tries to cause anger spikes to get pleasure in return.

This causes the frequency of these events to increase exponentially, until they are basically constant, leading to a result antipodal to the desired outcome.
The man escapes the hospital before the doctor, who detected this feedback loop from his charts, can actually stop the treatment.

The man then tries to destroy the hospital computer, which is located in the basement, but he is stopped before he can do much damage.

### Other information from the story

The story itself should have been written around the '70-'80, because the computer was as large as the room (the basement).

If you need any more information, please ask in the comments and I will try to answer as best as I can, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This sounds a lot like "[The Terminal Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminal_Man)" (1972) by Michael Crichton. For the record, it was a full length (albeit short) novel, not a short story. Also, he's not attacking the computer because it's controlling his stimuli, he's attacking it because he's gone doo-lally.

> *The events in the novel take place between March 9 and March 13, 1971.
>   Harold Franklin "Harry" Benson, a computer scientist (specializing in
>   artificial intelligence) in his middle thirties, is described as
>   suffering from psychomotor epilepsy[2] following a car crash he had
>   endured in 1969. He often has seizures followed by blackouts, and then
>   wakes up hours later with no knowledge of what he has done. During his
>   seizures, he severely beats two people; the day before his admission,
>   he had been arrested after attacking a third, a gas-station attendant.
>   He is a prime candidate for an operation to implant electrodes in the
>   amygdala region of his brain in order to control the seizures, which
>   will be performed in the Neuro-Psychiatric Service of University
>   Hospital. Two NPS surgeons, John Ellis and Robert Morris, are to
>   perform the surgery, which is unprecedented for the time. In modern
>   medicine, such a device would be called a neurostimulator; in the
>   book, it is referred to as a 'brain pacemaker'.*